# Admob showing over a listview in tab layout

Tags: android, layout, admob

i have a TabLayout that has a ListView to show as intent. I would like to put an admob banner in this layout, but it goes over the ListActivity, over the last item of the list i defined before. How can i get this working?

Posting now the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a14f67193b8a3e1"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 3433B134225900EC" >

        </com.google.ads.AdView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the AdView to take up it's own space and not sit on top of other content, I usually use a `RelativeLayout` and tack `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` onto my AdView and  `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` onto my top level content view.

Comment: To more specifically answer your question, the AdView is hovering over the bottom of your list because you've got two LinearLayout elements.  Android composits these over each other inside most basic ViewParent objects, which is why the ad floats over the list, rather than holding the space.  Eric's RelativeLayout approach will work, but you could achieve the same effect by putting the AdView into the first LinearLayout, and then putting the FrameLayout into a ScrollView to make that the scrollable element.