# Adding an Admob banner to a listview every X rows

Tags: java, android, android-listview, admob

I know this question has been asked multiple times. I have gone through a lot of the tickets here on stackover flow and I cannot seem to find anything that I can clearly understand.  I have been able to get an Admob Banner to appear in my app, but I am unable to figure out how to get it into my listview.  I pointers and/or help would be greatly appreciated.

[Putting an AdMob native ad in a listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578798/putting-an-admob-native-ad-in-a-listview][1])

Here is my adapter where I want the banner ad to appear.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        League league = leaguesList.get(position);



        if (position == 0) {
            // Create and return Ad View
            //int id = league.getId();
            //String leagueId = String.valueOf(id);
            //holder.id.setText(leagueId);
            holder.name.setText("BANNER GOES HERE");
        } else {
            // Create and return a normal View
            int id = league.getId();
            String leagueId = String.valueOf(id);
            holder.id.setText(leagueId);
            holder.name.setText(league.getName());
        }



        //Formatting And Displaying Timestamp
        holder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(league.getTimestamp()));
    }
```

This is my code for the banner ad

```
// Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK

        //setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

        // Find Banner ad
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Display Banner ad
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

I am not sure how to incorporate the ad code into the view holder inorder to make it work.

Again any assistance would be appreciated.

League Adapter Code (Modified)

```
    public class LeagueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeagueAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<League> leaguesList;

    public void notifyDatasetChanged(List<League> newleagueslist) {
        leaguesList.clear();
        leaguesList.addAll(newleagueslist);
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        private TextView leagueAverage;
        public TextView id;
        public TextView timestamp;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            id = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSeriesName );
            leagueAverage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueAverage);
            timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        }
    }


    public LeagueAdapter(Context context, List<League> leaguesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.leaguesList = leaguesList;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AdView mAdView;
        public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
            super(view);
            mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

     @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        //        .inflate(R.layout.listview_league, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
         viewHolder = null;
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch(viewType){
            case 1:{
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_league, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_league_admob, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolderAdMob(v);
               break;
          }
       }
       //return (MyViewHolder) itemView;

       return new MyViewHolder(viewHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //League league = leaguesList.get(position);

        League league1 = leaguesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        switch(holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 1:{
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.name.setText(league1.getName());
                viewHolder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(league1.getTimestamp()));
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return leaguesList.size();
    }

    //Formatting TimeStamp to 'EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)'
    //Input  : 2018-05-23 9:59:01
    //Output : Wed May 23 2018 (9:59:01)
    private String formatDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)");
            return fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10"
    android:focusable="true">

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeriesName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/leagueValue"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        autofit:minTextSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLeagueAverage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeriesName"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:text="League Average: 300"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeriesName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Fri May 18 2018"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLeagueId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvSeriesName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timestamp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- set Banner ad position in UI layout design -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to Override `getItemViewType` and return another type 
for each even position (%).

In `onCreateViewHolder` use viewType to deltermine which viewHolder you gonna use.
You should have two viewHolder's with different layouts (or one with set visibility).
One viewHolder will be a normal item of your list.
the second one will hold adView.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in many ways. The simplest one is adding the adview inside the list item layout itself and making it visible or invisible from onBindViewHolder. You can add an additional integer variable say 'viewType' to the League class inorder to identify whether the actual row item to show or the adview to show. Before passing the list to adapter, iterate through list and add an item for advertisement at intervals you need. Then you can simply check the viewType and show or hide adview and real row item content.

Inside Activity / Fragment (Before sending list data to Adapters constructor)

```
int interval = 0;
for(League model : oldList){
   if(interval == 5){
      list.add(new League(1, param, param));
      interval = 0;
   }else{
      model.setType(0);
      interval ++;
   }
   list.add(model);
}
```

set adapter after the above code.

You don't have to write the iteration code in onBindViewHolder. Your onBindViewHolder must look like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    League league = leaguesList.get(position);

    if(league.getType() == 1){
        //Adview. Shoe Adview and hide item viewgroup / items
    }else{
        //Row item content. Hide Adview and show item viewgroup / items
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have posted my full adapter and xml code above.  I tried, to implement your suggestion, but I am still unsure how to properly implement it.  I am still fairly new to Android programming. Could you please assist me with getting this working?

Comment: @RobertVogl Updated my answer. Please check and let me know if you need any assistance

Comment: There are a couple of things that I am struggling to piece together. 1. `list.add(new League(1, param, param));` - What does parm, parm represent? 2. Where does oldlist come from or where would it be declared?

Comment: @RobertVogl 1.This is adding objects to the list that you should pass to adapter. I just meant you can use a parameterised constructor if you want, however it doesnt have any role in this problem (You can create objects in the way you like).      2.-  The oldList here represents the actual list of objects you are using now to populate recyclerview. In that loop you have to manually add objects one by one to a new list. And you have to pass this new list to adapter instead of the old one. You can declare it the same way you follow now as long as it is accessible while creating adapter.

Comment: I have placed my modified LeagueAdapter above.  I am not sure if I am on the right track, but I think so.  When I compile the app  I am getting a ViewHolder cannot be converted to View in the Build Output screen.  Logcat it telling me the following, not quite sure on how to fix this error.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field `'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference`

Comment: You are checking viewType in onCreateViewHolder but there is no viewType you are passing. You have to override getItemViewType method and return 1 or 2 (1 and 2 you are using in oncreateviewholder) based on your condition (In your case if position is devisible by 5).

Comment: I had the whole project wiped out during a windows clash, lost my entire hard drive.  I believe I had this working, I will revisit this once I have the project back.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am back to the point where I am adding adds to the list items.  However the ad is laying over top of a list item.  I have started a new thread for this issue, could you please have a look.  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769770/admob-showing-over-a-listview-in-tab-layout)